# Virtual PBX for automated attendant and SIP clients

Tags: sip, pbx, freepbx

I have a task to make our own virtual PBX for automated attendant and SIP clients.

Scenario is following: We have our SIP account given from our voice carrier now I want to share these lines with other of our branches outside of our LAN network. I want also to be able when someone calls our public numbers to get the automated attendant and be able to call someone in our private PBX network (other SIP clients ).

Now I am looking for some good software for PBX.
I'll be most happy with some preinitialized distribution of some system.

Temporarily, I testing [pfSense](http://pfsense.org/) with port of [FreeSWITCH](http://www.freeswitch.org/). I also know about [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/), but there is lot of work to implement this solution. 
So I am asking you for a recommendation if there is some box which is already tested, reliable and if it is possible free.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: @ChrisS What is propuse i closing question 3 years old ? Getting reputatin, Showing power, Hate Mondays, Killing time ?

Comment: Is that it *should* be closed not enough reason? If not, newcomers find these old questions and think that Shopping Questions are acceptable on [SE] sites. If they're closed with an explanation we get less new Questions that have to be closed. In the end it's less work for me, so I suppose you could blame laziness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trixbox is pretty good (http://www.trixbox.org/). It's basically Asterisk but shake'n'bake style. Their community edition is a free version which installs Asterisk plus some fancy front-end tools among other things. It has IVR (auto-attendant), SIP support, remote extensions and other cool stuff. Try it out.

Comment: +1 for trixbox I'd also like to add that if your looking for an alternative to paid-for g729 protocol support check out http://asterisk.hosting.lv/   I have a customer that's been using it in production with great results

Comment: Agreed.  Have Trixbox running at home with Cisco phones.  Works real well.  Also, I hope you are not trying put this system in a virtual environment.  PBX systems rely heavily on timing and the VM just will not work 100% running a PBX.

Comment: Ill try with TrixBox also temporally I trying to configure AsterixNOW are there huge differences between these two systems